# OSMDroid Points of interest using multiple facilities

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, point-of-interest, osmbonuspack

I am using OSMDroid with its bonus pack to display a map and get point of interest near a location, but I can't find a way to get POI of different type in once.

As indicated in the documentation I am using the function getPOICloseTo() but it doesn't seem to handle a null facility to return all types of POI.

```
val poiProvider = NominatimPOIProvider("OSMBonusPackTutoUserAgent")
val pois = poiProvider.getPOICloseTo( GeoPoint( geoPoint ), "cinema", 10, 0.1 )
```

If there is a way to avoid making one call per POI type I would like to know it !

Thanks in advance, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with Nominatim service. You can dig in Nominatim API doc (having a look at [Special Phrases](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Special_Phrases)).

Alternative: move to [OverpassAPIProvider](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/OverpassAPIProvider). A little bit complex, but super-powerful. I'm quite sure it will match your need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was indeed not possible to combine many special phrases or includes differents amenity, so I had to find another way to do my research